# onchange issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I was creating select box and i write change function for select box in jquery.it works fine. but my problem is when ever i move the cursor in select box option, with out selecting any option, i click out side the select box . but the change function is calling i don't know how to fix this my code is given bellow

and my fiddle is  http://jsfiddle.net/6mhed8yL/

```
<select name="selecting" id="selecting" >
    <option selected="selected" >--Control--</option>
    <option id="Select All ">Select All</option>
    <option id="Remove All " >Remove All</option>
    <option id="Sample Questions" >Sample Questions</option>
    <option id=" User Added Questions">User Added Questions</option>
    <option id="Show All Questions" >Show All Questions</option>
                </select>
```

Jquery

```
$('#selecting').change(function(){
        alert("check");
        var opt=$('#selecting').val();
        var url="";
        alert("option is"+opt);
        //  $("#selecting option:selected").removeAttr('disabled');
             //$( "#selecting option:disabled" ).val( opt );
            //$("#selecting option[value=" + opt + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');


        if(opt=="Select All")
            {
             $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
             $("select option:contains('Select All')").attr("disabled","disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Remove All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Sample Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('User Added Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Show All Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");


            }
        else if(opt=="Remove All")
            {
            $("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false); 
             $("select option:contains('Remove All')").attr("disabled","disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Select All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Sample Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('User Added Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Show All Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        else if(opt=="Sample Questions")
            {

             $("select option:contains('Sample Questions')").attr("disabled","disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Select All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Remove All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('User Added Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Show All Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
            url = "SampleQuestions.jsp";
            alert("sample");

            /*  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    req.open("GET", url, true);

                    req.onreadystatechange =callback;

                    req.send(null); */



            }
        else if(opt=="User Added Questions")
        {
             $("select option:contains('User Added Questions')").attr("disabled","disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Select All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Remove All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Sample Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Show All Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Show All Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");

            url="UserAddedQuestion.jsp";
            alert("user");

        /*   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    req.open("GET", url, true);

                    req.onreadystatechange =callback;

                    req.send(null);
                     */

        }
        else if(opt=="Show All Questions")
            {

             $("select option:contains('Show All Questions')").attr("disabled","disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Select All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Remove All')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('Sample Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("select option:contains('User Added Questions')").removeAttr("disabled");
            url="ShowAllQuestions.jsp";
            alert("all");

            /*  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    req.open("GET", url, true);

                    req.onreadystatechange =callback;

                    req.send(null);
                     */

            }



    });
```

Comment: your fiddle need to select option `no wrap - in <head>`

Comment: what you described isn't happening to me, your original code should work fine.

Comment: all that repetetive code could sure be cut down a lot

Comment: see if the input event (instead of change) fixes it because it handles more scenarios at the expense on working in less browsers.

Comment: @Neverever make the mouse over in select box option than with out clicking any option.make double click in outside of select box.

Comment: @KVK Single/Double click outside of the select box still not firing `change` event as expected. Also tried `Bhumi`'s fiddle, all work fine. I start to think it might be your OS mouse setting.

Comment: @Neverever you are correct my os is ubuntu 14.0 that is the problem now only i check the same code in windows os it works good. what can i do to fix in ubuntu any suggestion using jquery

Answer (score 0):

I have updated jsfiddle now working.

Check here `[fiddle][1]` http://jsfiddle.net/6mhed8yL/1/

Comment: on first click out side the select box it didn't call the function but in double click it calls the function.check your fiddle update

Comment: remove alert and check ,it call function first time

Comment: my problem is os i am using ubuntu 14.0. but in same code works fine in windows. how can i fix it in ubuntu

Comment: I am also using ubuntu 14 and it's working fine here.